# How to handle like meaning sentences when working on text summarization

Tags: nlp, text-generation

Suppose we have a text like `Today is a very bad day. Very bad day is today. I wont come to play.`

What kind of technique should I use to summarize similar texts like above? From articles, I found over the web till now I think that *extractive summarization* will give importance to the first two sentences because major key points of the texts(according to the frequency of words) are present in the first two sentences. Similarly, the *abstractive summarization* technique will also make a summary certainly considering the first two sentences. But, in the ideal case, the third sentence is a must.

What should be my approach considering my text may have many sentences with similar meanings??

I am very new to this any kind of suggestion or help will be great.

Answer (score 0):

In case by 'summarize' you mean in fact 'classify', e.g. 'bad', 'good', etc, then an LSTM/GRU will do the job, just input the whole (truncated probably) sequence, and take the last state:

```
out, _ = lstm(embedding)
out_state = out[:,-1,:]
```

Here `embedding` is whatever word embedding you are using, `out` is the whole output of LSTM, and `batch_first=True` (in pytorch), so you take the last state as the input in the fully connected layer.

If you need to make predictions about parts of the text, just add a loop and truncate sentences rather than the whole text.